# Can someone please help me with the shading?

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, world

I'm a beginner to Blender and I have a shading problems.. I can't  see world theme in backgrounds.I use blender  2.83.2 version
First photo my pc:[image]

I want the see  in the second photo..

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: Click the little down arrow to the right of the preview circles and make sure "Scene Lights" and "Scene World" are un-checked.

Comment: thank u and The options were not selected, they were closed briefly, but I am still in the same situation...

Answer (score 0):

In material preview mode (the render mode you're using in your attached images), click the down arrow in the upper right corner of the viewport, just to the right of the render mode icons. Find World Opacity and turn it all the way up.